# Was Jesus a married man?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, art, leonardo-da-vinci

I was very confused about this so many times.  According to Leonardo da Vinci's painting some said that Jesus was a married man. Does the Catholic Church hide any truth?

Comment: You need to be more specific: which painting?  Who said it?  Can we have a quote? I assume you meant the Last Supper painting and who said it is Dan Brown in his conspiracy theory novel *The Da Vinci Code*, which has been debunked by scholars as *not* portraying history accurately.  Since this is a theology site, maybe Skeptics.SE is more appropriate.  The Catholic Church is indeed to be trusted to preserve the theological truths about Jesus pertaining to salvation, close to 2,000 years. Most denominations also say Jesus remains unmarried, so this is just mere speculation in the past 50 years.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

**Was Jesus a married man?**

The steadfast teachings and tradition of the Catholic Church is that Jesus was never married and remained celebrate his entire life.

Pope Benedict XVI, emphasized this as one of the points why Catholic priests do not get married in the Roman Rite: In imitation of Christ himself!

> In the Old Testament, the Levitical priests were obliged to abstain from sexual intercourse during the times when they were ministering in the temple.  Marriage was not incompatible with being a priest, yet sexual abstinence was deemed necessary prior to performing liturgical tasks.
>
> This understanding was enhanced in the light of Jesus Christ. Jesus, as the new and great high priest, was celibate throughout his entire life.  The reason for his permanent celibacy was that he lived his entire life in obedience to his Father.  He was always about his Father’s business in his Father’s house.
>
> The culmination of his total celibate commitment to his Father was his sacrificial death on the Cross. As celibate, the Spirit-filled Jesus became the perfect temple in whom, as the perfect priest, he offered perfect worship of the Father, the gift of Himself. Jesus’ celibacy manifested, confirmed, and perfected his total and unmitigated, liturgical and sacrificial self-giving of Himself in love.
>
> [Celibacy and the Priesthood](https://www.thecatholicthing.org/2023/04/30/celibacy-and-the-priesthood/)

[image]

[***The Last Supper*** (Leonardo da Vinci)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(Leonardo))

In the Last Supper painted by Leonardo da Vinci, there are are 12 men at the table with Jesus. The one immediately to the left is clean shaven and has no facial hair! Traditionally this is seen as the Apostle St. John who was the youngest of all the Apostles of Jesus Christ. Thus he is traditionally portrayed without a beard during the time Christ was preaching his Gospel of Good News.

[Is there a written tradition that would explain why John the Evangelist is often depicted in art as effeminate?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90549/is-there-a-written-tradition-that-would-explain-why-john-the-evangelist-is-often)